# Installation of Ethereum on ubuntu failing using ppa:ethereum/ethereum

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum

We are behind proxy. The proxy is already set.

Earlier we ran below commands and installed ethereum successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

But now when we are trying to install ethereum in new machine of same configuration it is throwing us following error :

---

Cannot add PPA: `'ppa:ethereum'`.

### Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

We checked other sites, but no success. Even Ethereum.org is showing the same commands. Is there any other way to install ethereum?

Please let me know if you need any more details. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

Answer (score 2):

Try: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`. If this doesn't work: try: `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum`. Adding the -E preserves user environment variables, which could be enough to get it working. Also, ensure the clock on the machine is set correctly.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct